# Probability of number sequence

Tags: combinations

A number is consist of 4 sequence numbers, 0 or 1.  First, we choose 4 numbers to make a number.  Next, we choose a number which differ in exactly two digits for the first one.  How many numbers can we take?

The answer is $2^4$${4 \choose 2}$.  How do you get ${4 \choose 2}$?

Comment: The wording of the question is very strange and should be improved.  A more mathematically correct and interesting wording of the question is "Given two random length4 bitstrings (*string using only digits 0 and 1*) what is the probability that they are hamming distance exactly two apart from one another? (*i.e. there are exactly two positions in the string which differ between the two strings*)"  to which the answer is $\binom{4}{2}/2^4=\frac{6}{16}=\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: I undrestand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very unclear, but $4 \choose 2$ has to come from selecting which digits differ from the original number.

Answer (score 1):

You have the number $a_1a_2a_3a_4,$ so you want $b_1b_2b_3b_4$ such that $$|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2|+|a_3-b_3|+|a_4-b_4|=2,$$
of course $0\leq |a_i-b_i|\leq 1$ so you have to choose out of the $4$ variables $2$(say $i,j$) such that $|a_i-b_i|=|a_j-b_j|=1.$ That can be done  in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.